# Scrollable button group in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anybody help me to create a button group.If there are more than an amount of X buttons in the group, it should have a left and a right arrow to scroll through all buttons without showing those all at once. In the end it should look something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQXLE.jpg]

I have tried this to create button group:

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <a class="button btn-days">Monday</a>
        <a class="button btn-days">Tuesday</a>
        <a class="button btn-days">Wednesday</a>
        <a class="button btn-days">Thursday</a>
        <a class="button btn-days">Friday</a>
        <a class="button btn-days">Saturday</a>
        <a class="button btn-days">Sunday</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you already have some css/js?

Comment: Apart from the HTML, what have you tried so far to make it happen ?

Comment: I got this: https://www.codeply.com/go/DclUsokAoV example. But I dont want to use bootstrap. I want to do only with jquery/javascript

Answer (score 1):

This could be done nicely using Bootstrap, simply add "**.pre-scrollable**" to containing div.

```
<div class="btn-group pre-scrollable" role="group" id="year">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">4</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery, they got methods like **find** that you can use to count the results and do any manipulations to the dom according to the result.

for example:

```
if($(".btn-group").find(".button").length > 3) { // then do something }
```

ref 
https://api.jquery.com/find/